# Каким образом вывести строку из prompt?

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом добавить строку в документ из prompt?

Comment: right way:  напишите свой способ, найдите в нём слабое место , и с конкретизируемым вопросом сюда... проще найти ошибку, чем написать всё за вас.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = prompt('String value');
document.write(string);
```

переменная string будет содержать значения из prompt,а дальше выводите куда вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только не учите людей использовать `document.write()` пожалуйста, это аттавизм со сложным поведением.

Comment: Согласен полностью с вами,я просто продемонстрировал автору вывод на экран для проверки и только!

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог!

Answer (score 0):

[Обратите внимание на тип возвращаемого значения (Return Value): String](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)
[А также тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/uibasic#prompt)